# Запуск сценария по cron'у

Tags: linux, bash

Нужно настроить создание бэкапов бд.

в каталоге `/home/ivanov` я создаю файл `bd_backup.sh`, в который добавляю:

```
#!/bin/sh
pg_dump site2 |gzip > db_site.gz
echo -e "Создание резервной копии базы данных завершено. " | mail -s "Backup on site.ru complate" ivanov@yandex.ru
```

Дальше делаю `crontab -e`

Добавляю в него `53 09 * * * sh /home/ivanov/db_backup.sh`. Т.е. хочу запускать сценарий каждый день в 9:53. Но ничего не происходит, ни бэкап, ни письмо на почту не приходит.

Права давал `chmod 750 db_backup.sh`

Может быть я что-то забыл? или где-то ошибка?

*(я впервые пробую запуск по крону)*

Comment: А если в терминале набрать `sh /home/ivanov/db_backup.sh`, то все отработает хорошо?

Comment: бэкап делается, а письмо  `db_backup.sh: mail: not found`

Comment: Если в скрипте уже есть шебанг, то крон сам поймёт какой шелл надо запускать

Comment: @dmitriy, надо писать абсолютные пути до скриптов. Крон в этом плане тупой.

Comment: Не забвайте, cron не тупой, он запускается в пустом окружении. Откуда бедному cron-у знать какое окружение потребуется конкретному джобу. Или запускаете ракушку типа `sh -l`  если под вашим именем, или   пишете обёртку, которая создаст необходимое окружение.

Comment: @dmitriy если вы только начали с кроном, попробуйте для начала - `env> cron.env`; или `false` - для теста ошибки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У меня была абсолютно та же проблема. Сделал так:

```
#! /bin/bash                                                                                                      
# Сохранение папки "Документы" на сервере                                                                         

LOG_FILE=/home/lary/.rsync.log                                                                                    
DDD=`date`                                                                                                        

echo "=== Начало архивирования: $DDD ===" >> $LOG_FILE                                                            
rsync -e 'ssh -i /home/lary/.ssh/rsync' --log-file=$LOG_FILE --stats --archive --delete \                         
        /home/lary/Документы  \                                                                                   
        larionov@172.17.133.129:/home/larionov/Archive/ >> $LOG_FILE  2>&1                                        
echo "=== Архивирование завершено ==="  >> $LOG_FILE
```